# How to serialize/deserialize a null List<T> with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I can serialize a `List<MyClass>` if the list is not null.

But if this list is null, I get an empty list on deserialization.

What do I have to do in order to get null on deserialization, when the list was null on serialization?

Here are my attempts so far:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("WorksButIsNoList", IsNullable = true)]
public MyClass[] WorksButIsNoList { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("ThrowsException", IsNullable = true)]
public List<MyClass> ThrowsException { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("IsntNull", IsNullable = true)]
public List<MyClass> IsntNull { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ThrowsException2", IsNullable = true)]
public List<int> ThrowsException2 { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("IsntNull2", IsNullable = true)]
public List<int?> IsntNull2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: XmlSerializer really isn't very interested in null lists... when deserializing, if it doesn't have data, it *won't touch the value*. Frankly, I would change your code such that you don't need to distinguish between a `null` list and an *empty* list.

Comment: During deserialization null lists are deserialized as empty lists.